# Where to put The Witcher 1 saves on Mac so that they can be imported to The Witcher 2?

Tags: macos, the-witcher-2

I have finished The Witcher 1 on PC a few years back and still have my final save I would like to import to the sequel. Now I'm playing The Witcher 2 on Mac, version downloaded from GOG.

Where should I put my Witcher 1 save so that it can be imported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have a save created during the Ice Plains or Order of the Flaming Rose Cloister portions of the Epilogue. The Witcher 2 recognizes only saves made before the last fight.

The save should be located under:

`"~/Library/com.cdprojektred.TheWitcher/The Witcher/Saves/"`

and the game save files should have a name like the following:

`xxxxxx - Order of the Flaming Rose-xxx.TheWitcherSave`

where xxxxxx is a serial number for the save.

Then, in TW2, select "New Game" then "Import Witcher 1 Save" from the main menu to import TW1 save.

Further info and files path for PC can be [found here](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Saved_game_import).

Comment: Great, thanks! Funny thing, I had already tried that before asking the question, but apparently the problem was that my save was called "Zakon Płonącej róży" instead of "Order of the Flaming Rose" and it was not recognized (probably because of Polish characters).

Answer (score 6):

The above directions are correct, for the MAC, as of around 2012 (these are my files). In 2014 however, using The Witcher from Steam, the location of saved files is "~/Library/Application Support/com.cdprojektred.TheWitcher/GameDocuments/The Witcher/Saves/".

For The Witcher 2, i.e., the place to copy the saved W1 file into, the location is "~/Library/Application Support/com.vpltd.THeWitcher2/GameDocuments/Witcher 2/gamesaves/".

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution as of 6/14/16

Something I wasn't getting was that your Witcher 1 saves must be copied into the default Witcher 2 save file location.

This is for steam version of game

*** These paths use hidden folders (Library) so you might need to make them visible. This link tells you how 
    http://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/quickly-showhide-hidden-files-mac-os-x-mavericks/

1. Default TWEE save file location:

   /Users//Library/Application Support/com.cdprojektred.TheWitcher/GameDocuments/The Witcher/saves
2. TW2AoKEE save file location without Cloud saving enabled

   /Users//Library/Application Support/com.vpltd.TheWitcher2/GameDocuments/Witcher 2/gamesaves
3. TW2AoKEE save file location with Cloud saving enabled

   /Users//Library/Application Support/Steam/userdata/33140344/20920/remote

**YOU MUST PASTE WITCHER 1 SAVE FILES INTO LOCATION (2) TO BE RECOGNIZED FOR IMPORTATION**

The Witcher 1 save must have the format of XXXXXX - Ice Plains(or later)-XXX.TheWitcherSave

Answer (score -1):

For the Macbooks.
If you can't find the folders with the search bar:
 1. Open a Finder window.
 2. Press "Go" at the top.
 3. Go down to "Go to Folder..."
 4. Paste Folder Directory in the space and OK.

Comment: What folder directory?